# Change APK name in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created an app using Android Studio but which I compiled and putting in my cellphone, the app name not change, appears other name (FolioReader). I already change app_name on strings and change name of packages. Someone can help me?
[AndroidManifest][1]
[Strings][2]

Comment: I tried running your project and it worked for me. It shows `Android E Book` as a app label.  Try uninstalling the app or clear the cache.

Comment: @Mayur Gajra on cellphone app appears Android E Book?

Comment: Yes. SS:  https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/7050352?key=88cf5952a755987c7cc7bc901e2f0276

Comment: @Mayur Gajra I'll try again.  Clear the cache of android studio or cellphone?

Comment: Cache/Data of that app only. In the settings. Try uninstalling as well. Try app in the emulator other device. To make sure it's not device specific.

Comment: @Mayur Gajra Ok, ty :)

Comment: @Mayur Gajra I follow what you say but doesn’t work  https://ibb.co/dj76gVm

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include all needed information in the post (this includes a minimal example, errors, logs, etc), not in images.

Comment: You completely skipped what I said. "**Information needed should be in the post, not in screenshots or external links.**" -- This means your Strings and Manifest should be embedded in the post, not in a link.

Comment: Also: @SauraTech -- **Reset your secrets now.** -- You just leaked 2 client IDs and secrets in your *Strings*, you forgot to blur them.

Comment: @Logan Devine will you help me?